# Unable to install mod_pagespeed when using cPanel-provided Apache 2.4

Tags: apache2, centos, cpanel, mod-pagespeed

After upgrading Apache to 2.4 I'm not able to install mod_pagespeed as it claims that my version is lower than 2.2.

```
# yum install mod-pagespeed-beta --skip-broken
...
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mod-pagespeed-beta.x86_64 0:1.3.25.3-2556 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd >= 2.2 for package: mod-pagespeed-beta-1.3.25.3-2556.x86_64

Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    mod-pagespeed-beta-1.3.25.3-2556.x86_64 from mod-pagespeed
```

I have checked my apache version using `httpd -v` command:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.4 (Unix)
```

It seems like version comparing script does not like the Unix part. Are there any solutions to this problems apart from downgrading?

### Update

Server environment is CentOS 6.4, Kernel `2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64`

I have downgraded Apache to version 2.2.24, but version formatting is still the same:

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.24 (Unix)
Server built:   Mar 14 2013 09:32:50
Cpanel::Easy::Apache v3.18.6 rev9999
```

And installer still does not like my Apache version.

Comment: Which distro is this?  `yum` is a Fedora/RHEL/CentOS tool, but the version used is very important.  More importantly, if RHEL or CentOS, how did you get Apache 2.4 installed?  Also, why are you using `--skip-broken`?  You should never *ever* need that.  *Ever*.   Can you give us the full and complete `yum` output, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems like version comparing script does not like the Unix part. Are there any solutions to this problems apart from downgrading?

That's not what's actually happening.  *`yum`* is complaining about the RPM dependencies:

```
Processing Dependency: httpd >= 2.2 for package: mod-pagespeed-beta-1.3.25.3-2556.x86_64
```

For some reason, it doesn't think that you have a modern Apache version installed.  How did you install Apache 2.4?  If you are using Redhat Enterprise Linux or a derivative (CentOS, Scientific Linux, etc), this is a very important question because 2.4 *isn't available* for the RHEL family in any official way.  They ship with 2.2.  You'd need to install 2.4 from a third-party RPM repository, or you'd need to compile it yourself.

Given that RPM naming is dead simple, I'm going to wager that you compiled it yourself.  Compiling the package and directly installing it (without creating an RPM from the compiled binaries and installing *that*) will *not* satisfy the requirement given by the RPM.

Even if it *did* satisfy the requirement, your own native compiled Apache *probably* won't safely or sanely load the precompiled binaries from wherever you picked up that mod_pagespeed RPM.

If you compiled Apache 2.4 yourself, [you're going to need to compile mod_pagespeed yourself](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/mod_pagespeed/build_from_source).

Comment: I have a CentOS server with cPanel, which offers Apache 2.4 upgrade. I believe it's compiling it

Comment: Yeah, you're going to have to compile by hand then.  Good luck.

Comment: I have downgraded Apache but issues is still exists

Comment: It's still using a custom-compiled version of Apache.  Again, if you're compiling Apache, you're going to need to compile the module.

Answer (score -2):

Please try with the below

```
yum install at

wget https://dl-ssl.google.com/dl/linux/direct/mod-pagespeed-stable_current_x86_64.rpm

rpm -u mod-pagespeed-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/mod_pagespeed/download

Comment: It was a first thing I have tried to do, usually it's working